# Cardinality of $[X]^\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In ZF, what do we know about the cardinality of the set
$$[X]^\kappa = \{ Y \subseteq X : |Y| = \kappa\},$$
where $X$ is a set and $\kappa$ is a cardinal?

Comment: What do you mean "what do we know about it"? It's an extremely vague question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is the range of values that $|[X]^\kappa|$ can take in different models of ZF?

Comment: You're just writing the same question. Which, again, is an incredibly vague question, since even in models of ZFC the range is pretty much "almost any size".

Comment: Does that mean that it is consistent for $|[X]^\kappa|$ to be any cardinal between $|X|$ and $2^{|X|}$?

Comment: Depending on $X$ and $\kappa$, sure. Since under ZFC, this is just the same cardinality as $|X|^\kappa$, provided that $\kappa\leq|X|$ anyway, that value could be almost anything.

Comment: So, if Choice fails, things are even worse I guess, $|X|$ and $[X]^\kappa$ can be incomparable for example. Is there any result that touches on the cardinality of $[X]^\kappa$ in such models? Is there any paper or book that talks about these sets? I browsed Jech, Kunen and Halbeisen, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I have only seen these sets mentioned in a setting related to Ramsey theory.

Comment: Look. You are asking an incredibly open question. I understand, it is an interesting one. But at the moment there is a large volume of open parameters here. Is $\kappa$ an ordinal? Is $X$ such and such? Are we assuming so-and-so axioms in addition to ZF? Each of these things will drastically change the answer to your question. It's good to "want to know generally about something", but this is not the intended use of this website. Ask a focused question, and if you have a particular application to this question, ask about *that* and work your way from there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Sumac No!!! It is a good question.